# Отсортировать по возрастанию элементы, находящиеся на четных местах

Tags: c, массивы, олимпиада

```
int A[15];
int i;
int q,aa, bb;
printf(" \n", i);
for (i=1; i<=15; i++)
scanf("%d", &A[i]);
 for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
if (i%2==1){
    for(int k=15-1;k>0;k--)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<k;i++){
        if(A[i]>A[i+1])
        {
            t=A[i];
            A[i]=A[i+1];
            A[i+1]=t;
        }
    }
}
}
printf(" A[15]{");
for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
{
    printf("%i,", A[i]);
}
printf("}\n");
```

Нужно отсортировать по возрастанию элементы, находящиеся на четных местах.

Comment: А зачем их перемещать? У вас же задача отсортировать их прямо в этом же массиве, как я понимаю...

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=15; i++) scanf("%d", &A[i]);` => `for (i=0; i<15; i++) ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чётных местах массива - это совсем  не то, что элементы с четным значением (которые у вас в аа подсчитываются).

А сортировку по четным индексам сделать нетрудно - берете любую простенькую сортировку и все индексы в квадратных скобках умножаете на 2

Comment: Не вижу в вашем коде сортировки